# errors using Subversion in Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android-studio, svn

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 2.2 and attempted to use it on an existing project that had been checked out of a Subversion 1.9.3 repository.  After the upgrade, multiple different Subversion-related operations that used to work fine are failing with various errors.  Some things still work, others are met with a variety of errors. For details on some of the errors, see this link:[android studio 2.2 issue 223358](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223358)

Is anyone else seeing errors with Subversion operations (commits, etc) after upgrading to Android Studio 2.2?  Has anyone upgraded and can still successfully use Subversion functions from within Studio 2.2?  Even better, has anyone else seen problems and found a fix :-) ?

Thanks in advance for any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have all this problems too. How i solved it:
In Android Studio  Settings - Subversion setting - tab General I have switch off checkbox "use command line client" (Also switch off "Enable interactive mode" checkbox). After that svn browsing begin to work fine. Than I import Project to Studio from svn server and in new imported project all svn features works fine.